# DataTrigger WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatrigger

I have two lists. List of Things and List of Fruits. If an item in the list of things is a fruit from the fruits list, I would like that item to be highlighted.

I would like this with data-binding and thru xmal and not code-behind b/c I am doing MVVM pattern. I have tried it with DataTrigger and Converter but can't get it to work. Please help.

Thanks.

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Things}"
        Name="ListOfThigns"
        Grid.Row="1">
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Fruits}" >
                    <Setter Property="ListBoxItem.Background" Value="Green"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Fruits}"
        Name="ListOfFruits"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Grid.Row="1">
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: If you are implementing MVVM, you should have a view model where a Thing has an `IsFruit` property. You would bind the DataTrigger to that property.

Answer (score 0):

Or, if Fruit inherits from Thing (a fruit is a thing):

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
        <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dm:Fruit}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="RoyalBlue"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dm:Thing}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.Resources>
    </ListView>
```